# FABRIC_E_SERVER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED: CertificateNotMatched

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-service-fabric

I have .net core project utilizing service fabric.  I set up a build pipeline to deploy to my service fabric managed cluster in azure.  When setting up the service connection type step, I utilized the cert I associated with my cluster.  It is a self signed cert in keyvault.  During the deployment process I keep getting the following error

```
FABRIC_E_SERVER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED: CertificateNotMatched
```

The stack trace is as follows

```
2022-01-26T21:41:13.0165883Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=warning]Failed to contact Failover Manager Service, Attempting to contact FMM...
2022-01-26T21:41:13.0587416Z ##[debug]System.Fabric.FabricServerAuthenticationFailedException: FABRIC_E_SERVER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED: CertificateNotMatched ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80071C44
2022-01-26T21:41:13.0600016Z ##[debug]   at System.Fabric.Interop.NativeClient.IFabricQueryClient12.EndGetPartitionList2(IFabricAsyncOperationContext context)
2022-01-26T21:41:13.0611858Z ##[debug]   at System.Fabric.FabricClient.QueryClient.GetPartitionListAsyncEndWrapper(IFabricAsyncOperationContext context)
2022-01-26T21:41:13.0623788Z ##[debug]   at System.Fabric.Interop.AsyncCallOutAdapter2`1.Finish(IFabricAsyncOperationContext context, Boolean expectedCompletedSynchronously)
2022-01-26T21:41:13.0635475Z ##[debug]   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2022-01-26T21:41:13.0854075Z ##[debug]System.Management.Automation.PipelineStoppedException: The pipeline has been stopped.
2022-01-26T21:41:13.0865504Z ##[debug]   at System.Management.Automation.MshCommandRuntime.ThrowTerminatingError(ErrorRecord errorRecord)
2022-01-26T21:41:13.0876005Z ##[debug]   at System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError(ErrorRecord errorRecord)
2022-01-26T21:41:13.0886710Z ##[debug]   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.CommonCmdletBase.TestClusterConnection(IClusterConnection clusterConnection, Boolean testNetwork)
2022-01-26T21:41:13.0897006Z ##[debug]   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.ConnectCluster.ProcessRecord()
2022-01-26T21:41:13.0913858Z ##[debug]System.Management.Automation.PipelineStoppedException: The pipeline has been stopped.
2022-01-26T21:41:13.0924251Z ##[debug]   at System.Management.Automation.MshCommandRuntime.ThrowTerminatingError(ErrorRecord errorRecord)
2022-01-26T21:41:13.0934735Z ##[debug]   at System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError(ErrorRecord errorRecord)
2022-01-26T21:41:13.0944961Z ##[debug]   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.ConnectCluster.ProcessRecord()
2022-01-26T21:41:13.1818805Z ##[debug]Leaving Connect-ServiceFabricClusterFromServiceEndpoint.
```

I'm not sure where to start in order to track down what its looking for here.

Answer (score 1):

I also had similar issue and tried with multiple certificates. Each of the certificates used were deployed to the nodes. The only one that successfully matched was the `Primary` certificate.

There two ways of confirming the primary certificate.

1. Service Fabric Explorer: Go to the explorer url (Your service fabric explorer url can be gotten from the Service Fabric Cluster Overview page in Azure portal). Click on cluster (side menu) and then Manifest tab. Find the certificate xml definition and confirm the certificate thumbprint referenced.

[image]

2. Azure Portal: Go to the service fabric cluster resource and click on `Security` under the `Settings` menu. The `Cluster Certificate` section has the primary certificate thumbprint.

[image]

Update cluster service connection in Azure Devops(ADO), using the details of the primary certificate and trigger the deployment again.

- Cluster Endpoint: `tcp://SF_NODE_IP:19000` (Check the load balancer resource in azure portal to confirm generated IP Address)
- Server Certificate Lookup: Common Name or Thumbprint
- Server Certificate [Common Name(s)|Thumbprint(s)]: Check your certificate
- Client Certificate: Certificate's Base64 encoding. This can be retrieved using this PowerShell command:

```
[System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("REPLACE_PATH_TO_DOWNLOADED_CERT.pfx"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The 'certificate not matched' issue, which occurs when one of the parties in a Service Fabric-to-Service Fabric connection presents a certificate that fails the recipient's validation requirements, is one possible cause for connection attempts to be terminated.
According to this MSFT [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/cluster-security-certificates#troubleshooting-and-frequently-asked-questions), To troubleshoot the error `'FABRIC E SERVER AUTHENTICATION FAILED,'` determine which certificate is being presented on each of the nodes attempting the connection; study the certificate and try to copy the validation rules (check for thumbprint or common name equality)

Answer (score 0):

The Azure DevOps connections to the new Managed type SF Cluster have this weird behavior.  I had to go in SF Explorer to the Manifest section, copy the x509FindValue and use that autogenerated value in Azure DevOps Connection's "Server Certificate Common Name(s)" box.  The Certificate's body and password are just identical to what's in the physical file.  TOTALLY unexpected not to be able to use the actual Certificate's Common Name.

Answer (score -1):

Fix your service connection by navigating to your service fabric cluster explorer url

https://mysfurl.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:19080/Explorer/index.html

Then look at the certificate information and copy the certificate thumbprint into thumbprint or "issued to" into common name for the service connection.

Deployment will succeed